# Opening a PDF embedded in iframe in chrome with content security policy > plugin-types

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, content-security-policy

I have the CSP (Content-security-policy) plugin-types policy set to white-list pdf type as below. When trying to open a PDF file in iframe with src attribute, It is working well with browsers IE 11, and Firefox 47+ but failing in Chrome 50+. What else is required to make it working in chrome?

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' plugin-types application/pdf;
```

**Error in chrome console**

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf
Refused to load 'http://127.0.0.1/module123/open.do?id=10000' (MIME type '') because it violates the following Content Security Policy Directive: 'plugin-types application/pdf'. When enforcing the 'plugin-types' directive, the plugin's media type must be explicitly declared with a 'type' attribute on the containing element (e.g. '<object type="[TYPE GOES HERE]" ...>').
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem.

To resolve the problem, I needed to add blob: to the object-src directive.

Also, I did not need to specify plugin-type.

So it would be:

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' blob:; style-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';`

Answer (score 1):

Adding `blob:` did not do the trick for me but the following did:

```
frame-src data:;
```

Comment: It depend on how you opening your file. If you use `<iframe src='blob:http://your-urls/your-content`>` then you should use `frame-src blob:;` but when you open file with prefix `data:http://your-urls/your-content`  then `frame-src data:;` will work. You can use also both solution in one config.