# Chrome displays PDFs with limited height

Tags: css, google-chrome, pdf, content-security-policy, hugo

Consider [this](https://impulsiv.fs.tum.de/pdf/impulsiv138.pdf) document.

On Firefox, everything is fine:
[image]

However, on Chrome, the document height is limited:
[image]

I'm generating the website with (an older version of) Hugo. Does anyone have an idea what's causing this?

Comment: At first I thought it's a `CSS` issue, but I hadn't realised it's a PDF file. Unfortunately, I don't think it has anything to do with `CSS` or Hugo, for that matter. It's just the way your browser renders the PDF file, nothing to do with your website. Have you tried opening other PDFs with Chrome? Same result?

Comment: @AMoustache Other PDFs work just fine. Other users have reported this issue as well. Does Chrome render it correctly in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the developer console in Chrome you can see some errors. Didn't think of doing this first, because it was just a PDF, what could go wrong with it? Well,

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-[redacted]'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

(5) Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'".
```

This is what the HTTP response looks like.

```
> GET /pdf/impulsiv138.pdf HTTP/1.1
> Host: impulsiv.fs.tum.de
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2020 05:52:33 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Jun 2020 15:36:36 GMT
< ETag: "4805f5-5a821312d6900"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 4720117
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
< X-Frame-Options: deny
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';
< Content-Type: application/pdf
<
```

Your HTTP server is filling in that [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) header, either explicitly by you or some defaults from your host.

After some more digging, it seems that it's a common issue with Chrome loading PDFs:

- [How to set CSS for embedded PDF viewer with CSP enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358335/how-to-set-css-for-embedded-pdf-viewer-with-csp-enabled)
- [Opening a PDF embedded in iframe in chrome with content security policy > plugin-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795479/opening-a-pdf-embedded-in-iframe-in-chrome-with-content-security-policy-plugin)

I'm not entirely sure what changing those directives imply, but that's your lead.

If displaying the PDFs in the browser is not a hard feature request, then I would suggest to simply instruct the browser to download them (see the [`Content-Disposition` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)). If it is, then I'd try making a page to wrap the PDF and display it there, maybe you have more control this way.